# Activate voice recognition with keyword

Tags: voice-command

I want to have the mic listening for a keyword and then have it turn on Google recognizer? Has anyone been able to do this and how? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The name escapes me at the moment, but there is a voice-command app in the Market that does just that. I don't think it uses the Google voice command engine, though.

Comment: Vlingo? There's a similar feature on my S2, but there's also a cautionary piece of advice - battery life will be noticeably shortened.

Comment: Are you asking that it would run all the time in the background? Wouldn't that consume a lot of resources/battery to "wait" for a command word?

Comment: Yes.  Samsung's S-voice and Nuance's [Dragon Mobile Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.balerion) do exactly that.  They do also warn you that it does drain the battery.  Not sure how much they drain, as I've never used that feature.

Comment: Until we can put the mic in a low power state and not need to keep the phone awake for it to work, we aren't going to get something that is actually usable without an external power source handy.

Answer (score 1):

This is something added Android 4.3 and is featured on the Moto X. The phone passively listens all of the time for you to say "Okay Google Now" followed by whatever your command is. (There's a special low-powered CPU being used to listen, which is why it's not available on every device with 4.3.)

(Here's a [video demo by Slashgear](http://youtu.be/ZpeRr5QgRYU).)

I expect to see this more frequently as new hardware comes on the market.

Comment: I was under the impression that this is not a feature of Android 4.3, but rather an additional software feature added by Motorola to take advantage of their voice hardware. Am I wrong?

Comment: You could be right. I don't have a source to hand which gives a definitive answer either way.